# Disable some permissions for apps in Java Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm writting application, which main usage is to catch all installed applications' dangerous permissions. I got one question: is there any option to disable this permissions by my application?

Comment: no, there is not

Comment: @TimCastelijns any chance?